# jQuery Pass input attribute to a function and check if it exist

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to check if an attribute exists on an input element. I created a hasAttr plugin as you see below to check if attr is undefined and false. Everything appears to be written correctly, but I'm not getting any response or errors.

**HTML**

```
<form id="form">
    <div><input type="text" /></div>
    <div class="selected"><input type="text" /></div>
    <div><input type="text" /></div>
</form>
```

**jQuery hasAttr plugin**

```
$.fn.hasAttr = function(name) {
    return this.attr(name) !== undefined && this.attr(name) !== false;
};
```

**Function for passing attr name** If attr exist then set value abc else alert false

```
function formeditvalues(attr) {
    if ($('#form').find('.selected input').hasAttr(attr)) {
        $('#form'.find('.selected input').val('abc');
    } else {
        alert('false');
    }
}
```

**Calling the function gives no response.**

```
formeditvalues('type');
```

Check jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/KPczs/1/

Comment: Sometimes there are implied attributes for some tags if the attribute is not in the HTML explicitly (i.e. `type` for `input`). http://jsfiddle.net/KPczs/4/ (the last input should return `false`?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in the console, you're missing a `)`, here:

```
$('#form'.find('.selected input').val('abc');
         ^
```

Fixing this to:

```
$('#form').find('.selected input').val('abc');
```

...[makes your fiddle work](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/KPczs/2/)

---

As an aside, `false` is a valid attribute, for example `disabled` and `readonly` are examples of boolean attributes in the DOM, so your `!== false` may not be a desired check.  There's also the [`[attr]`](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/) (has-attribute` selector) you can use as well, [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/KPczs/3/):

```
$('#form .selected input['+attr+']').val('abc');
```

Comment: Thanks. Console for some reason was not responding. I had to restart fireFox to see the error. Indeed i missed the `)`.  I appreciate the other pointer you posted.